# Complexity of Sparse Matrix Cholesky decomposition

Tags: python, julia, sparse-matrix, gaussian-process

I am having trouble finding a straightforward answer to the following question:

If you compute the Cholesky decomposition of an nxn positive definite symmetric matrix A, i.e factor A=LL^T with L a lower triangular matrix, the complexity is O(n^3). **For sparse matrices, there are apparently faster algorithms, but how much faster?**

**What complexity can we achieve for such a matrix with say m<n^2 nonzero entries?**

**Edit**: my matrix is also approximately main diagonal (only the diagonal and a some adjacent diagonals below and above are nonzero).

P.S I am eventually interested in implementations in either Julia or Python. Python has the sksparse.cholmod module (https://scikit-sparse.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cholmod.html) but it isn't clear to me what algorithm they are using and what its complexity is. Not sure about Julia, if anyone can tell me.

Comment: Wikipedia has a page on Cholesky decomposition. "When it is applicable, it is roughly twice as efficient as the LU decomposition." –

Comment: Code can be faster without changing complexity.  Actual speed usually is a mix of some sort of fixed setup code plus a per-elemment-complexity that depends on the number of elements.  But with sparse, times way also depend on the sparsity, the number of nonzero elements relative to the total number.  And with languages like python there's the added interpreted vs compiled factor.  I expect to see complexity discussed in theoretical papers with narrowly defined comparisons; it's less useful in working code.

Comment: Sparse solvers tend not to be amenable to complexity analysis as they're heavily influenced by the sparsity structure. Not just how many non-zeros there are, but where they are. I tend to see performance evaluated empirically as in: https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/1236463.1236465

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can only be answered exactly for abitrary matrices if P=NP ... so it's not possible to answer in general.  The time complexity depends on the fill-reducing ordering used, which is attempting to get an approximate solution to an NP hard problem.

However, for the very special case of a matrix coming from a regular square 2D or 3D mesh, there is an answer.  In this case, nested dissection gives an ordering that is asymptotically optimal.  For a 2D s-by-s mesh, the matrix has dimension n = s^2 and I think about 5n entries.  In this case, L has 31*(n log2(n)/8)+O(n) nonzeros, and the work is 829*(n^(3/2))/84+O(n log n).  For a 3D s-by-s-by-s mesh with n = s^3, there are O(n^(4/3)) nonzeros in L and O(n^2) operations are required to compute L.

Comment: Great answer! Could you share a reference to read further about the regular grid cases?

Comment: Yes, see https://archive.siam.org/books/fa02/ .

Comment: Also https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01396660

Comment: And the original paper is here: https://doi.org/10.1137/0710032

Answer (score 0):

The Python Library Numpy (Numerical Python) also has a module for cholesky - [np.linalg.cholesky](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.cholesky.html), I have provided the link to the docs although I am not sure if this answers the question, might need some experimentation.

Comment: Agnij, thanks. But I am mostly interested in the complexity.

Answer (score 0):

It's worth looking at an incomplete Cholesky decomposition, which there multiple variations of but typically either only compute the entries in the triangular factor that are nonzero in the input, or use a low rank approximation of the decomposition. It's not clear from your question why you are interested in the asymptotic complexity but with the Gaussian process tag I can guess that you're decomposing a covariance kernel matrix and repeatedly solving a linear system during inference. The incomplete factorization is most often used as a preconditioner in these kinds of applications- while it's not exact, it's very efficient, easy to update incrementally, and can greatly accelerate solvers.

In application, however, the answer to your question is very, very likely to be irrelevant to the approach that performs best for your purposes. There are $O(n log(n)^k)$ time algorithms for incomplete factorizations that are of no practical use for the same reasons as the algorithms for matrix multiplication with the lowest exponents. Knowing what precisely you need for your application will inform your options but you already have far and away the best tools to find out- taking a few minutes writing some code to generate synthetic data or sample varying sizes of your real data and timing it in the same way that you're interested in for application. If you're doing one factorization and solving many systems, the time to do the factorization is likely going to be dwarfed by the solving. If you are doing many factorizations, especially from scratch each time, the constant and linear factors of the running time will have even more impact. Plus, the sparsify patterns and kernel itself can have an enormous impact on the performance with the same algorithm. It's not difficult to construct kernels that have fully dense covariance matrices, tridiagonal precision matrices, and a Cholesky factorization that is just the lower triangular portion of the matrix exactly up to scaling by a diagonal matrix (an exponential kernel in 1d has all 3 simultaneously). Profile first, optimize last.